# Activity Feed Not Working on my website

Tags: facebook, android-activity, feed

I cannot get the activity feed to show the updates on my FB page on my web page. The url is [www.briggroseunder7s.co.uk](http://www.briggroseunder7s.co.uk)

It is showing random info from facebook, Below is the code i am using.

```
<div class="fb-activity" data-site="www.facebook.com" data-action="like,comment" data-width="300" align="center" data-height="300" data-header="true" data-colorscheme="dark" data-font="tahoma" data-recommendations="true" ></div>
```

I am only an amateur and trying to get this working for my kids football site. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: www.briggroseunder7s.co.uk --- make me unseen it!

Comment: The plugin seems to be functioning correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In your code example above, `data-site="www.facebook.com"` is incorrect.  What you need there is your website's url where the activity is happening.